# Burned pan health issue

Tags: pan, stainless-steel, electric-stoves, burnt

I cooked my eggs with my pan and forgot to turn the stove off after removing the eggs. Later on, my pan got a huge burn mark and so I threw the pan away. Should I replace the electric stove as well? I'm worried that the chemical might leak from the pan to my stove.

Comment: what kind of pan was it? nonstick? you can't really ruin a cast iron pan by burning it, so the pan matters to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

It is unlikely that the burned residue from eggs warrants either tossing the pan or the stove.

In fact, depending on what the pan is made of, you could likely clean it and continue to use it and the likely worse thing that would happen would be the next thing you cook in the pan might have a burned flavor.

If stoves had to be thrown away every time something on them got burned stove manufacturers would sell a **lot** more stoves.